# Why does my ASP.NET 5 Application Not Run On IIS 7.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm running ASP.NET 5 (Core) with IIS 7.5. I've already installed httpPlatformHandler and set the physical path of the site (in IIS) to the wwwroot folder that I published from visual studio 2015. All I get is the blank continuous loading page. I am pretty sure I have everything wired up correctly. Also, it loads up fine if I uncomment out the app.Run statement from within the Configure method and comment out the app.UseIISPlatformHandler, app.UseDefaultFiles, app.UseStaticFiles and app.UseMVC.

My Code is below. I don't know what else to do at this point. Any suggestions? If any other code snippets are needed, let me know.

Startup.cs (Configure method)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();

        //app.Run(async (context) =>
        //{
        //    var greeting = greeter.GetGreeting();
        //    await context.Response.WriteAsync(greeting);
        //});
    }
```

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
```

**New Edit. I've updated my folder structure to MVC (using Controllers, Views, etc) and I've changed the Configure method a bit. Now it loads a blank screen and the console is logging a 404 not found. Anymore suggestions?**

Adding my full Startup.cs:

```
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsetting.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
        ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("connString").Value;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        //app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseFileServer(true);
        app.UseMvc(routes => 
        {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
```

Comment: Do you get any error message? Do you see anything in the event viewer?

Comment: Negative. I get the blank continuous loading page. No error at all

Comment: I used to get an error, then I downloaded the httpplatformhandler, and now it does this.

Comment: What version of the platformhandler? You need version 1.2 (or higher) for this.

Comment: I downloaded v1.2 however where would I go to double check the version?

Comment: Are you trying to access static files or an MVC route? Have you tried both?

Comment: All I need to access is my single index.html page, so I suppose I don't need that app.UseMVC. That's in there due to a tutorial I was working. I'm new to ASP.NET5. That shouldn't be the issue though, correct? It works fine when I run it from visual studio.

Comment: Just confirmed, I do have version 1.2.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET 5 (now Core 1.0)? Make sure you use RC1 Update1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the IIS logs to see if the request is even making to IIS?

You can also try putting a simple middleware module inbetween each middleware module defined in the Configure() method of class Startup.  Your middleware can write a message to the Windows event log stating where it's at in the Http pipeline and the contents of the response body.  Kind of like putting in alerts to debug Javascript.  That will at least let you know where it's hanging up or clearing the response body.

I posted a very easy to understand demo on github that demonstrates how to create middleware in three easy steps. Click [here](https://github.com/ClintBailiff/MiddlewareDemo) to go to that demo.

UPDATE:
Try changing your Configure() method to the code below (put in your own route if mine isn't correct for your setup).

```
app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: I just checked the logs and I'm seeing a lot of "HTTP/1.1 GET /MyApp - 1 Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue No Managed Pool." Now, I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Is this a different machine than the one that succesfully displays the page when you're running within Visual Studio?

Comment: Nope. Same machine. I actually have VS up right now piddling with it. It's so weird. Just did a little research on that error code and evidently it's some sort of worker that is crashing when my startup gets called I think. I'm going to add the rest of my startup.cs code above

Comment: I'm updating my answer with something to try.   You are running ASP.NET 5 RC1 right?

Comment: I just saw the extra comments where you say you're only trying to access a static index.html file.  I think all your problems will go away if you use an index.cshtml file with a controller.  Is there a special reason you don't want to use MVC?

Comment: No reason. This is the first project using Core, so I figured I'd start of simple. Does the controller folder need to be in the wwwroot folder or under the solution root?

Comment: I mainly kept it away from MVC because it is just a SPA. No need for a controller. I'll try this and see if it works.

Comment: The wwwroot folder is for static files only.  Since this is your first Core app, I'd suggest building from and/or modifying the standard template project.  And since Core is still not released, I'd stay within the standard way of doing things. Middleware is a big part of Core.  That should be one of the first things you familiarize yourself with.  I spent a lot of time figuring it out.  That's why I posted an easy to understand demo of how to develop middleware.  Check out my github link I posted in my answer.  The readme file for that project explains how to search the code for what you need.

Comment: Will do. Unfortunately the MVC route didn't work. It worked fine with Express through VS, but when I published it, I got the same result as before.

Comment: It's my suspicion that trying to use an IIS default page isn't supported yet.  Core takes a totally new approach towards web servers.  Where everything previous relied on IIS, now the web server is interchangeable and all authentication and authorization is done in middleware before the request even gets to IIS. Core is a whole new paradigm.  Almost nothing you know about the inner workings ASP.NET still applies. It's based on the OWIN model.  Do some reading on how it's based on the OWIN model and the middleware concept will make more sense.

Comment: An up vote would be nice.  I've always been a lurker on SO and github.  But since I had the opportunity to work in ASP.NET 5 for past 12 months or so, I feel I have something to contribute.  I'll be posting more demos on github in next few months.  So keep checking back.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the help Clint. Hopefully I'll figure this issue out!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: I think your problem will be solved if you use an MVC page instead of a static html page.

Comment: I changed it to a home controller pulling in a view and the same thing happens. It works in Express, put not IIS

Comment: Now, when I publish the app through VS, is creates 3 folders: approot, logs, and wwwroot. I'm suppose to be setting my physical path in IIS to the wwwroot folder, correct?

Comment: So, now I've changed the startup.cs Configure method and altered it to mirror the MVC structure (controller, views, etc). See above for the code. Now it loads a blank screen and the console logs a 404 not found (localhost/app)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, I didn't have email alerts turned on. Here's my web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It could be the identity that your Application Pool is running under. The identity user has to have a number of dnx paths in its PATH environment variable. So it's easiest just to set your username as the Application Pool identity because you should have those paths in your PATH environment variable.

EDIT: When we setup our QA machine we had to create three System environment variables and point them to the user profile that installed RC1. Those are:

```
DNX_HOME - C:\Users\<username>\.dnx

DNX_PACKAGES - C:\Users\<username>\.dnx\packages

DNX_PATH - C:\Users\<username>\.dnx\bin\dnvm.cmd
```

And the Application Pool identity user obviously needs to have access to those paths.

Comment: I solved it yesterday! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460967/asp-net-core-404-error-when-published-to-iis-7-5/36478567#36478567

I had to add a Configure1 method for some mapping. Unfortunately, now the WebAPI doesn't work when on IIS, but it works on express. I'm thinking it has something else to do with a mapping, but now instead of a 404 error, it's a 500 error. Here's my other question I have out (WebAPI Issue) if you feel like giving your expertise! ha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483610/asp-net-core-webapi-500-internal-error-in-iis-7-5?noredirect=1#comment60581223_36483610