# ASP.NET Not Publishing to IIS - 500 or 404 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am trying to publish my ASP.NET MVC Core website to IIS 8.5. I've published the package locally and get three folders: "approot", "logs" and "wwwroot". I then have to manually copy all three folders to my web server e.g. `D:/inetpub/wwwroot/myWebsite/<CopyHere>`.

Should I simply copy "approot", "logs" and "wwwroot" directly to "CopyHere", or elsewhere?

When I attempt to view the website, I simply get a blank page (e.g. "http://my.web.site"). If I enter my Controller and Action to the URL (e.g. "http://my.web.site/myController/myAction") then I get a 404 error status.

Comment: Your site should have an app pool assigned to it in iis.  Each app pool can be run as a certain user/service account.  Ensure the user/service account that runs this site's app pool has proper permissions: e.g., read/execute permissions for code files/folders and read/write access to your log files/folders.

Comment: I assume that this part of IIS has been setup correctly by our network guy. We initially started with an default.html page and an hyperlink with an image attached. Just those two files were dropped straight into "~/wwwroot/myWebsite/" and it displayed straight away. Along comes MVC Core and it's a whole new ball game. Where do I place the folders?

Answer (score 1):

This has been an issue with ASP.NET Core RC1 for everybody.  ASP.NET Core RC2 came out yesterday.  I hope it fixes the many issues of publishing a project to IIS.  But I've yet to try it.  You can download ASP.NET Core RC2 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows). And go [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html) to read the instructions on migrating from RC1 to RC2.

I wouldn't suggest even bothering with the very buggy RC1.  But if you want to try and make it work, first make sure you have httpPlatformHandler v1.2 installed. Then follow the steps and issue resolutions [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/12/running-asp-net-5-website-on-iis/). If it still is not working, I've heard some people have resolved their issues by adding a Configure1() method in Startup.cs. See the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460967/asp-net-core-404-error-when-published-to-iis-7-5/36478567#36478567).

**EDIT**:
Here is the folder structure for RC1.

approot
logs
wwwroot

You point your website to wwwroot.  The contents of wwwroot should be the same as the wwwroot folder in your project.

Also, make sure you set the .NET CLR version on your application pool to **No managed code**.

Comment: Hi Clint. I will do some digging on ASP.NET Core RC2 now. On a side note, can you advise on how the folder structure of "~/wwwroot/myWebsite/" should look?

Comment: What did you do with the "approot" and "logs" folders? Where did you place these on the web server?

Comment: All three go in the same directory e.g. D:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\.