# ASP.NET Core WebAPI 500 Internal error in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm struggling to get this WebAPI to work. Well, work with IIS. Everything works fine in IIS express, but when I publish it, specifically 1 api request doesn't work. I'm trying to access a url of `API/[Controller]/{date}/{integer}`. I keep getting the 500 server error. My other route of `API/[Controller]/{date}` works.

Here's my API Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class PostingsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/Postings/5
        [HttpGet("{date}")]
        public string Get(string date)
        {
            return date;
        }

        // GET api/Postings/20160407/2
        [HttpGet("{date}/{modeID}")]
        public List<TruckPosting> Get(string date, int modeID)
        {
            TruckPosting tp = new TruckPosting();
            List<TruckPosting> truckPostings = tp.GetTruckPostings(date, modeID);
            return truckPostings;
        }
    }
```

Could the reason be that I'm trying to return a List<>? I'm stumped considering it works fine in VS's IIS Express.

**Edit**

Here's my startup.cs page:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

public void Configure1(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
                app.UseDefaultFiles();
                app.UseStaticFiles();
                app.UseFileServer(true);
                app.UseMvc();
            }

            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                app.Map("/appRoot", (app1) => this.Configure1(app1, env, loggerFactory));
            }
```

Comment: Did you check the server's event log?  Usually a 500 is caused by an exception and often you can find those details in the `Application Log` on the IIS machine.

Comment: you could investigate to the use of your string date parameter

Comment: @Infer-On What do you mean?

Comment: @CodingGorilla The logs don't have anything in particular. Just some Time Idle logs and some 404s. Is the syntax correct? e.g. can I pass in a string parameter, then an integer? ({date} being the string, and {modeID} being the int)

Comment: Now, I haven't done any WebAPI mapping in my startup.cs file. I've done 1 mapping for the application itself.

Comment: @BrandonTerry Yea, your syntax looks fine, and the fact that it works in IIS Express (which is for all intents and purposes just IIS) tells me that it's something configuration wise on the IIS server.  You checked the event logs, (e.g. `eventvwr.msc`) right and not the IIS logs?  The other thing to do is change your `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` in your web.config and hit the API with a browser to see if you get a yellow screen error with more details.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Where would I find those log files at? Unfortunately the custom errors mode didn't do anything. There's something weird between Core and IIS 7.5. I struggled to finally get even the application to run. It all had to do with mapping. I had to use app.map in my startup.cs file and I'm thinking that could be the issue with the API. For some reason IIS isn't using the proper URL or something.

Comment: I think your routing looks pretty strange. Why are you mapping a single route like that instead of setting up general mapping in your UseMvc in configure?

Comment: Not sure. The app wouldn't even load until I finally found that app.map solution and now it loads, but the API's won't work.

Comment: @Merryweather wouldn't that require me to use Controllers and Views? I think the reason I didn't do that was because this is just an SPA. I didn't find a need to use a controller and/or view. I'm pulling my content from the default.htm within the wwwroot (I'm new to Core. This is my first project with it).

Comment: Yes controllers, you're already do. Views no! The routing does not have anything to do with views. But it should work with only attribute-based routing. I think it can have something to do with you `branching` `app.Map("/appRoot..`. What happends if you remove that line it test purpose?

Comment: @Merryweather If I remove the app.map(), it runs fine in IIS Express through VS, but the application returns a 404 when I publish it to IIS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a good thought that it might that fact that you're returning a List.  We have working Core Web API methods and all of them return `Task<IEnumerable<Foo>>`.  Try changing the return type `List<TruckPosting>` to `Task<IEnumerable<TruckPosting>>`

EDIT: To view the details for 500 (internal server) errors you will need to put the following line of code at the beginning of your Configure (or Configure1) method:

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

And obviously this is not something you want in a production environment.

EDIT2: When running in VS you can use the code below to show exception details as long as the Hosting:Environment variable in the Debug section of Properties is set to "Development". After publishing you will need to create a System Environment variable named ASPNET_ENV and set its value to "Development" or the code will not call the UseDeveloperExceptionPage() method.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

Comment: That's why you want to use`if (env.IsDevelopment())` so you don't have to add and remove the `dev exception page`

Comment: Yeah, but I didn't know how he was publishing his project so I didn't go into setting the Environment variable to make that work.  On second thought I probably should have.  I'll update the answer to show that.

Comment: Alright, so I've narrowed it down. It's something to do with the list of objects that I'm returning. I figured that out because if I just return a simple list of a few strings, it works fine. I don't know how to debug it. The app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage doesn't change anything. In what order does it need to go in?

Comment: @ClintB Alright, I got the error message to show up. It's not the list that I'm returning that is the issue, it's the SqlClient that I'm using to get the data. It says "Unable to load DLL "mycpu path\sni.dll". Any ideas?

Comment: @ClintB Just figured it out. I was publishing the app with dnx-coreclr-x64 instead of x86. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: You're getting it done Brandon!  It sounds like you figured it out but for future reference error handlers should be added before any other middleware.  The order you put things in the Configure() method is the order they are executed in the Http pipeline.  So the first middleware component in the Configure() method is the first one executed during the request and the last one executed during the response.

Comment: I had the same type error & had my dev exception page disabled. Took me 2 days to get here. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I posted an ASP.NET Core custom exception handler on GitHub today.  I thought it might be helpful to you since you're building an SPA and are probably calling a lot Web API methods.

It's a middleware project that returns error messages for Web API calls and redirects to an error page for non Web API calls.  It can also log the exceptions in a SQL Server database.  That's done in a separate thread to help with performance.

The solution includes a demo application that shows how to use the exception handler for both Web API exceptions and non Web API exceptions.

Here's the link.
https://github.com/ClintBailiff/CustomExceptionHandler

If you end up checking it out and have some suggestions or comments, I like to hear them.